# \parencite in footnote: where to put the full stop?

Tags: footnotes, citing, punctuation

*I am not entirely sure, if this question fits the agenda of this site. I you feel that it does not, please accept my apologies.*

Just a brief question:

If I have a footnote with a quote, then  reference the quote by `\parencite`. I am always uncertain, wheher I should place the full sopt after the `\parencite`or before it.

1. Cf. this wonderful quotation: "Wonderful quotation" (Author, Title, p.12).
2. Cf. this wonderful quotation: "Wonderful quotation." (Author, Title, p.12)

   `1. \footnote{Cf. this wonderful quotation: \textquote{Wonderful quotation} \parencite[12]{key}.}`

   `2. \footnote{Cf. this wonderful quotation: \textquote{Wonderful quotation}. \parencite[12]{key}}`

I recall having been told, that you should *always* end a footnote with a full stop. But with parentheses, it looks odd to me.

I tried to look in my Oxford Style Manual, but couldn't find an advise. Anyway, I am open for advise that is not from the Oxford Style Manual.

Comment: It all depends on which set of typographic rules you stick to. Are you writing British or American English? Brits generally do not put full-stops marks inside the quotation, so the first option would apply. Americans put punctuation marks within the quotation, so perhaps the second option would work in US English. What would seem faulty to me is to use *double* punctuation marks (e.g. end of quotation, if you are quoting a full sentence, and end of footnote).

Comment: In my experience, the normal expectations are: `'this is quoted text' (citation reference).`  That is, the rule about the period coming inside or outside the quotation marks only applies when there is not a parenthetical citation.  However, if you are using footnotes, the use of `\parencite` should be strictly limited since most footnote-heavy documents use other forms of citation (AFAIK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from a point of view of the *Real Academia Española* (RAE homepage [here](http://www.rae.es), explanation [here](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-esquina-del-idioma-parentesis-combinado-con-punto-de-cierre-5438/)), endpoints should ALWAYS go at the end, regardless if the parenthesis  are present or not.

Like so, your first option should be the one used:

*Cf. this wonderful quotation: "Wonderful quotation" (Author, Title, p.12).*

Comment: I've looked through some books published by CUP and OUP and both seem to second your recommendation.